Closure of pure philosophy question for being "off topic"
Ethics, environmental philosophy, the role of man in relation to nature, Rousseau, and the Romanic movement are all legitimate philosophic topics on this board, yet this question on them was closed for being off topic.  Here is the question:  Is there an ethical view that we should always do what is most naturally human?  That one DISLIKES Romanticism is not a legitimate reason to try to close questions about that philosophic movement! Is that what was behind the close votes?  Is there any legitimate reason to close this question?

Seems like a fine question to me. If you get 4 reopen votes, let me know and I'll be the 5th.

Voted to reopen, thanks for bringing to everyone's attention.

The linked question is not clearly asking for any of those mentions, and that would be the minimum for a good question here. Just because a topic is interesting does not mean any and all questions remotely possibly related to that topic are good here. That one LIKES romanticism is not a legitimate reason to keep bad questions open.

@tkruse "I read about philosophical topic X but I forget the details or what it's called, can you help me?" is a fine question for the site. People wanting to know more about philosophy they read is THE most firmly on-topic type of question.

For my taste, the question is unnecessarily loaded with slant and fluff. If it really was just about the title question, no problem. But it seems to me the cancer stuff belongs to what the OP read, which both invalidates Rousseau et al. and hints at some fringe stuff that hardly qualifies as philosophy.

@PhilipKlöcking It's possible/likely that the asker read some actual philosophy at one point and then their memory of it drifted over time and got filled in with their own associations, such as the cancer stuff. I looked into some cancer stats just now, and it is apparently true that hunter-gatherers die from cancer at lower rates, even age-adjusted, than modern people. Age-adjusted cancer incidence and death in the US has been flat or declining since 1975, with the exception of lung cancer which followed the incidence of smoking.
